# Is not there something curious behind jtdz-solenoids.com/stackoverflow_?

Tags: discussion

What is [http <strike>***s***</strike> ://jtdz-solenoids.com/stackoverflow_](http://jtdz-solenoids.com/stackoverflow_)?

Is not there something curious behind this website? Any legal implications maybe?

It is just nothing to care about...? It looks like a static copy of SO. Just curious.

Comment: Once you become an established user on the site, you can just search your username on Google and find a seemingly endless stream of such copy sites (if you have a unique name).

Comment: @Carcigenicate Indeed the named I used (on google) was unique, i.e. *NewtornM****L***ga*. But this actually not the name of an established user on SO though. Also, I tried with yours, nothing came up. Just like mine, too generic.

Comment: If nothing came up with mine, Google had autocorrected it. My username is a made-up word based on "carcinogenic".

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes I know. Obvious depending on our (native) language. Actually I have forced google to search exactly what I asked him for.. There was no auto-correction. It ***looks like*** Google has done something *very recently* because even the name I used henceforth returns nothing.